# PHP for directory as opposed to a file

Tags: php, navbar

I am using PHP to bring in the navbar into my pages.  The following code allows me to set the active page so that I can style the links.

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == "/caseStudies.php") { ?>
```

I am struggling with how to make it work on a drop-down menu.  I have put the 4 pages into a sub-directory and I want to be able to style the title of the dropdown section when any one of the 4 pages is active.

I have tried:

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == "/services/") { ?>
```

Services being the name of the directory, but it doesn't work.

Is there another command other than `'SCRIPT_NAME'` that will look for the directory rather than the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because your `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` will be something like this: `/services/page1.php` and it is of course different than `/services/`. What you want to do is to check if `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` starts with `/services/` and you can do that with strpos https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php.

```
var_dump($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']); // string(15) "/services/a.php"
var_dump($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == "/services/"); //  bool(false)
var_dump(strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], "/services/") === 0); // bool(true)
```

If you want directory it is also possible with dirname https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php. So wrap `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` with dirname and you will get the dirctory and can just compare with `/services`:

```
var_dump(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])); // string(9) "/services"
var_dump(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) === '/services'); // bool(true)
```